# Can I convert a CSS style to an Image in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx-8

I have a window launcher which is created dynamically and the toolbar buttons are styled with the following CSS for example:

```
.toolbar-button-open-notepad {
    -fx-background-image:  url("../images/buttons/notebook_edit.png");
    -fx-background-size: 24,24;
    -fx-background-position: center center;
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;

     -fx-min-width:24;
    -fx-min-height:24;
    -fx-pref-height:24;
    -fx-pref-width:24;
    -fx-max-height:24;
    -fx-max-width:24;
}
```

What I would like to do is set the stage.getIcons().add() to the image stored in this css reference.  However I have not been able to find away to do that.  Is there a way to get that information so that I don't need to hardcode references to my images in my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have applied CSS to your scene, retrieving the image assigned to a given node through the property `-fx-background-image` can be done easily just by using the `Node.getBackground().getImages()` method.

This simple test shows how this can be done.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello World!"));

    VBox box = new VBox(btn);
    box.getStyleClass().add("box");

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
    root.getChildren().add(box);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    Region node = (Region) root.lookup(".box");
    if (node != null) {
        Image image = node.getBackground().getImages().get(0).getImage();
        System.out.println("Image " + image);
    }
}
```

where `style.css` is just:

```
.box {
    -fx-background-image: url("icon.png");
    -fx-background-size: stretch;
}
```

Note this has to be done after the stage is shown. Otherwise you will need to have the node added to the scene and call `root.applyCSS()` and `root.layout()` before calling the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Class ExtendedStage extends Stage` that contains a new `StyleableProperty` that holds the image.